# What is wrong with my if condition?

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I've been trying to figure this out for like three hours.  I believe the syntax is correct but the method isn't working.  This class takes an arrayList of type Point2D (class I defined) which holds the x and y elements of a point.  I am attempting to order the arrayList by the ascending point sizes (ex. (200, 200), (200, 400), (400, 200), (400, 300), (400, 400)...etc, so sort x points, then y points).  The if condition in the for loop of the indexOfSmallest smallest, if I am correct should be working, but it will only sort the x values correctly.  Any ideas?  Thank you in advance!!

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Point2DSelectionSort {
    public Point2DSelectionSort() {
    }

    public static void sort(ArrayList<Point2D> a) {
        int index, index2,indexOfNextSmallest;

            for (index = 0; index < a.size( ) - 1; index++){
              indexOfNextSmallest = 
                            indexOfSmallest(index, a);
              interchange(index,indexOfNextSmallest, a);
            }

            //a.get(0), a.get(1),...,a.get(index) are sorted.
     }

    /**
     * Precondition : i and j are legal indices for the ArrayList a.
     * Postcondition: a.get(i) and a.get(j) have been interchanged.
     */
     private static void interchange(
                                int i, int j, ArrayList<Point2D> a) {
        Point2D temp;
        temp = a.get(i);
        a.set(i, a.get(j));
        a.set(j, temp);
     }

    /**
     * @return  the index of the lexicographically first value among
     * a.get(startIndex), a.get(startIndex+1),...,a.get(a.size( ) - 1)
     */
    private static int indexOfSmallest(
                                 int startIndex, ArrayList<Point2D> a) {
        Point2D min = a.get(startIndex);
        int indexOfMin = startIndex;
        //Point2D otherPair = (Point2D) min;
        for (int index = startIndex + 1; index < a.size( ); index++){

            if((a.get(index).getFirst() < min.getFirst()) || (( a.get(index).getFirst() == min.getFirst() ) && ( a.get(index).getSecond() < min.getSecond() ))){
                   min = a.get(index);
                   indexOfMin = index; 
            }

        }
        return indexOfMin;
   }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried putting in some print statements?  How about breaking your `if` statement into nested pieces with print statements inside each layer?

Comment: Yeah, definitely break the `if` into several statements (assigning their results to `boolean` variables) and then `println` the resulting values.

Comment: Your `if` condition looks okay to me. Have you tested it separately? Perhaps the problem is elsewhere. (P.S. The loop would be easier to comprehend if you declared a variable `Point2D probe = a.get(index);` at the top and then used `probe` instead of `a.get(index)` throughout the rest of the loop body.)

Comment: Your best bet is to go through the code with a debugger....

Answer (score 0):

Your entire class is unnecessary, because it can be replaced by a call to `Collection.sort()`

```
List<Point2D> list; // assuming

Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Point2D>() {
    public int compare(Point2D a, Point2D b) {
        return a.x == b.x ? a.y - b.y : a.x - b.x;
    }
});
```

Voila!

---

If this is an assignment, and you must use the class, incorporate this code into your method (discarding all but the sort method):

```
public static void sort(ArrayList<Point2D> a) {
    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Point2D>() {
        public int compare(Point2D a, Point2D b) {
            return a.x == b.x ? a.y - b.y : a.x - b.x;
        }
    });
}
```

Job done.

To specifically answer your question of "what's wrong with my if statement", the answer is "it exists".

Comment: Yes, but the entire class is entirely necessary if it's an assignment! After all, somebody needs to learn how various sorting algorithms actually works (without just calling a stock API). (I'm not the downvoter, btw.)

Comment: @TedHopp sure, but learning the JDK API *is* learning the language. Answer edited btw to offer a compromise.

Comment: Judging from the comments (including those that were removed by Dave Newton's edit), the assignment is to implement selection sort. For that, OP really does need a method that finds the index of the smallest element at or beyond a given index.

Comment: @Ted `<soapbox>`can you tell that these kind of assignments get my goat? In the real world, any programmer who implemented such code would be sacked. Asking students to not use libraries is breeding bad habits.  Is it too much to ask teachers to set coding problems that don't have a library solution? `</soapbox>`

Comment: @Bohemian In real world is the Key here,but for learning the algorithms I think these kind of assignments are perfectly valid. Whats wrong with understanding how a particular method works? Nothing bad can some of it. In real world they should know not to reinvent the wheel (box shaped probably :-) but that's up to the individual not to be stupid...

Comment: I'll stand on that soapbox with you! When I learned how to implement these kinds of low-level algorithms, it was out of Knuth and we did our assignments in MIX. No APIs for us! Just like you don't learn the fundamentals of woodworking by operating a computer-controlled lathe, students shouldn't be learning nuts-and-bolts concepts like selection sort using high-level tools like Java. There's a fundamental mismatch between the language (and its APIs) and the concepts being taught.